# MySQL NOT IN performing strange

Tags: mysql, sql

If I run the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mag2
WHERE  environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_host_label LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_host_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_local_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_date_added LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_description LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_label LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_owner LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_sample_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_source LIKE '%test%'
        OR task_state_state LIKE '%test%'
        OR task_state_state_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_return_code LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_runtime LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_start LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_global_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_owner_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_state_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_task_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_task_start LIKE '%test%'
        OR event LIKE '%test%'
```

I get a result of 249.  I want to eliminate 100 results from the query using NOT IN with the tasks_task_id which is a unique index on the database and does not have any duplicates.
My statement with AND NOT IN is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mag2
WHERE  environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_host_label LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_host_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_local_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_date_added LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_description LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_label LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_owner LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_sample_type LIKE '%test%'
        OR samples_source LIKE '%test%'
        OR task_state_state LIKE '%test%'
        OR task_state_state_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_return_code LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_runtime LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_env_start LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_global_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_owner_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_state_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_task_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR tasks_task_start LIKE '%test%'
        OR event LIKE '%test%'
           AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ( '1762', '1763', '1764', '1765',
                                        '1766', '1779', '1787', '1836',
                                        '1837', '1838', '1839', '1840',
                                        '1841', '1850', '1852', '1856',
                                        '1893', '1914', '1927', '1946',
                                        '1955', '1957', '1969', '1985',
                                        '1986', '2016', '2026', '2038',
                                        '2063', '2098', '2110', '2133',
                                        '2136', '2148', '5056', '5066',
                                        '5068', '5070', '5084', '5106',
                                        '5120', '5132', '5136', '5146',
                                        '5150', '5152', '539', '546',
                                        '547', '548', '549', '550',
                                        '551', '557', '563', '565',
                                        '587', '589', '590', '594',
                                        '602', '603', '621', '622',
                                        '623', '624', '625', '626',
                                        '627', '637', '640', '642',
                                        '643', '645', '646', '648',
                                        '650', '651', '656', '657',
                                        '658', '662', '663', '664',
                                        '665', '671', '672', '675',
                                        '676', '677', '687', '688',
                                        '691', '693', '695', '699',
                                        '701', '702', '756', '762' )
```

It is yielding a result of 150 instead of 149 and I can't figure out why.  I also tried AND != and got the same results.  Could someone please explain why?

Comment: perhaps this is the goddess of punishment for too long lines speaking to you

Comment: Check your task ids, so a select * from mag2 where tasks_task_id in(...) to see if you really get 100 results

Comment: May be you got number wrong. If the numbers you don't want are in the db, why aren't you doing a left join, instead of writing them out one by one. I don't even want to ask how someone came up with a schema that left you with all those likes. It's awful!

Comment: Next time, please [format your query](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm). It helps everybody to understand it better, including yourself.

Comment: That looks like a raw phpmyadmin query to find a particular word within a table.

Comment: Eeeeegads man why is your `WHERE` clause so out of hand. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Sorry guys new to S/O.  I checked using select * from mag2 where tasks_task_id in and got back a result of 100.  The reason for all the likes is for the user to select what column they want to query on.  I have 27 total columns and selected all to do a full table scan.  The 249 results are paginated to 100 results per page with a checkbox next to each with the tasks_task_id (Unique index) as the value.  When the user clicks the checkbox or select all (as in this case) then filter the query should re-execute with a NOT IN to filter out the results.

Comment: do you need parentheses around the `OR` things (`task_task_* LIKE '%test' OR ...`) but not around the `and`?  so..... `where (task_task_* LIKE '%test' OR task_task_* LIKE '%test' OR...) AND task_task NOT IN ...`

Comment: If I go to page 3 (49) results, click select all, and filter it works and returns 200 results (2 pages of 100 results).  Anything over 60 selected seems to be 1 off for a strange reason.  The select all value is removed from the array of task_task_id via array_shift which I suspect may be what is causing the issues here but my debug print statements shows it being shifted off fine and the array being a total of 100 elements ([0] - [99].  @ansh0l has the right idea it is essentially to find a particular word or string from a malware analyzer that I built a MySQL database for all the samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a logical issue. Be aware when using `OR` and `AND` together, as MySQL will interpret them like this:

```
condition1
OR condition2
OR (condition3
    AND condition4)
```

So, try to group all your `OR`s with parentheses as all of them are going to be like "one condition" AND "not in condition". Like so:

```
WHERE
(
    condition1
    OR condition2
    OR condition3
)
AND NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

So your query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM   mag2
WHERE  
    ( 
          environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR environments_env_type LIKE '%test%'
          OR environments_host_label LIKE '%test%'
          OR environments_host_type LIKE '%test%'
          OR environments_local_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_date_added LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_description LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_label LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_owner LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_sample_type LIKE '%test%'
          OR samples_source LIKE '%test%'
          OR task_state_state LIKE '%test%'
          OR task_state_state_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_env_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_env_return_code LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_env_runtime LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_env_start LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_exec_arguments LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_global_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_owner_risk_score LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_sample_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_state_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_task_id LIKE '%test%'
          OR tasks_task_start LIKE '%test%'
          OR event LIKE '%test%' 
       )
       AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ( '1762', '1763', '1764', '1765',
                                    '1766', '1779', '1787', '1836',
                                    '1837', '1838', '1839', '1840',
                                    '1841', '1850', '1852', '1856',
                                    '1893', '1914', '1927', '1946',
                                    '1955', '1957', '1969', '1985',
                                    '1986', '2016', '2026', '2038',
                                    '2063', '2098', '2110', '2133',
                                    '2136', '2148', '5056', '5066',
                                    '5068', '5070', '5084', '5106',
                                    '5120', '5132', '5136', '5146',
                                    '5150', '5152', '539', '546',
                                    '547', '548', '549', '550',
                                    '551', '557', '563', '565',
                                    '587', '589', '590', '594',
                                    '602', '603', '621', '622',
                                    '623', '624', '625', '626',
                                    '627', '637', '640', '642',
                                    '643', '645', '646', '648',
                                    '650', '651', '656', '657',
                                    '658', '662', '663', '664',
                                    '665', '671', '672', '675',
                                    '676', '677', '687', '688',
                                    '691', '693', '695', '699',
                                    '701', '702', '756', '762' )
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was my issue and I overlooked it because of all the dynamic query creation and appending that is occurring.  I am going to go back and fix where the query gets created to get my desired results

Comment: Awesome. Remember that [SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) tools always help in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

`AND` has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`, so your query is actually:

```
(..)
    OR tasks_task_start LIKE '%test%'
    OR ( event LIKE '%test%'
       AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ( ... ))
```

Put all `OR`s in brackets:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mag2
WHERE ( environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_id LIKE '%test%'
        OR environments_env_type LIKE '%test%'
    (...)
        OR tasks_task_start LIKE '%test%'
        OR event LIKE '%test%' )
           AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ( ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure to use parenthesis when combining different logical comparisons. For example, you want to use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
WHERE (var1 LIKE '%foo%' OR var1 LIKE '%bar%' OR ...) 
AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ('1762','1763','1764','1765','1766', ... )
```

The [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html) may come in to role here. In case all most of the task_ids come from the last table before 'AND', this might be the reason, because SQL could treat your query as it was like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
WHERE (var1 LIKE '%foo%' OR var1 LIKE '%bar%' (...) 
OR (
var1 LIKE '%zzz' AND `tasks_task_id` NOT IN ('1762','1763','1764', ... )
) )
```